# How to disable CSRF for a specific SIRD route in play?

Tags: scala, playframework

I can see from this [play documentation](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.8.x/ScalaRouting),`+nocsrf` can be added to each route that doesn't need a csrf filter.

Example:

```
+ nocsrf
POST  /api/new              controllers.Api.newThing
```

But the same `+nocsrf` is not working for SIRD based route like the example below

```
->      /api                        api.ApiRouter
```

ApiRouter.scala:

```
package api
import javax.inject.Inject
import play.api.mvc._
import play.api.routing.Router.Routes
import play.api.routing.SimpleRouter
import play.api.routing.sird._

class ApiRouter @Inject() (controller: ApiController) extends SimpleRouter {
  override def routes: Routes = {
    case GET(p"/") => controller.index
  }
}
```

[SIRD Play Documentaion](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.8.x/ScalaSirdRouter)

How can SIRD route in play accomplish the `+nocsrf` utility given by play or implement one?

Comment: Don't have the answer but did you try looking at the compiled `Routes.scala` file? Maybe you'll find some hints. I guess the `+nocsrf` is actually generating something else than the routes themselves.

Comment: @GaëlJ i did try it out. But still not very clear for me though